# How to make a checkbox look like a button and fit in all screen sizes

Tags: html, css

I have a checkbox below:

```
foreach($options as $indivOption) {
   echo '<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" id="option-' . $indivOption . 
        '" value="' . $indivOption . '" /><label for="option-' . $indivOption . 
        '">' . $indivOption . '</label>';
}
```

My question is simply how to convert a checkbox into looking like a button. I want the design to work on all browsers and work on all screen sizes but does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want?

Comment: [Duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499)

Comment: @David Like this fiddle but measurements to be able to work on all screen sizes, i think the one in the fiddle is for a specifc screen size: http://jsfiddle.net/zAFND/4/

Comment: The key to this question is I how to get the checkbox button look fine in all screen sizes (using %) as that it could be displayed on a laptop, computer or ipad screen for example

Comment: @user1723760 Just use `width:40%`? I don't see how it can't be displayed poorly on different resolutions.

Comment: @David This what happens when I put width as 40%: http://jsfiddle.net/zAFND/612/ The button goes shorter

Comment: @user1723760 Play around with padding?

Comment: @user1723760 No problemo. Just be sure to close this question. I'll put my own answer up.

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/checkboxes/ I guess this is what you need. Inspect the code and study the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to play around with padding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a html <label> element:

```
<label>Button<input type="checkbox"></label>
```

then you use CSS to style the label and hide the checkbox (using position: absolute with a negative top/left

```
label {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    background: red;
    ...
}

label input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    top: -9999px;
}
```